# Cannot access Take() on a List<object> with System.Linq referenced in using

Tags: c#, razor, generic-list, razorengine

I am using RazorEngine for email templating. I have introduced Take() method into the template. I did this so the authors can dictate how many records they want without us having to change any C# in our code directly. I have tried adding the using statements to the template itself as well as using the fluent configuration and adding the namespaces needed but I am not having any luck.

Error:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Take'
```

Here is my fluent configuration for RazorEngine:

```
        var config = new FluentTemplateServiceConfiguration(c => 
            c.IncludeNamespaces(
            "System",
            "System.Linq",
            "System.Collections",
            "System.Collections.Generic"));

        using (var service = new TemplateService(config))
        {
            //Razor.SetTemplateService(service);

            dynamic dyModel = model;
            var parsed = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheName)
                ? service.Parse(template, dyModel,null, cacheName)
                : service.Parse(template, dyModel,null,null);

            return parsed;
        }
```

If I purposely state a namespace incorrectly, I do get an error saying it couldn't find it so I know that it is processing the config data but despite that, I am still getting the error.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I am passing in a dynamic model which either is a List or has a List on it.

Comment: hmm.. you are on .Net 4.5 - can you show the actual razor code? what's inside dyModel?

Answer (score 0):

So this was kinda lame, there is a ticket on RazorEngine's wiki that states this was fixed, so either I am using it wrong or it hasn't been fixed but this is what I had to do to get it working in the razor file.

```
var topFive = ((List<dynamic>) Model.MyList).Take(5);
```